# Replace data by jput and ajax rather than append data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using ajax and jput to show a list of data from database and I call the ajax function every second. I want the table to be changed when there are new records in the database. The list was successfully shown at the first time but it appends the same set of data continuously rather than replacing the existing dataset. How to replace the dataset by jput rather than append it?

```
   function doAjaxlist()
    {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "list.php",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(result){
                       $("#tbody").jPut({
                            jsonData:result,
                            name:"tbody_template",
                        });
               },
        complete: function (data) {
              // Schedule the next
              setTimeout(doAjaxlist, 1000);
        },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
              console.log("fail");
            }
            });
    }
    setTimeout(doAjaxlist, 1000);
```

When there has new records in database,I expect the output at the 2nd ajax call will be:

```
Name | age
A    | 18
B    | 20
```

The output at the 2nd ajax call now:

```
Name | age
A    | 18
B    | 20
A    | 18
B    | 20
```

Comment: you can empty the table before adding new data like `if(result.length > 0){$("#tbody").empty();//add code here}`

Comment: explore function which instead of appending, it replace, $(#id).html('put stuff here')